# Oracle to Drupal 7 data manipulations

Tags: database, oracle, csv, drupal-7

I am building a Drupal 7 site and I have to access data from oracle, clean up and manipulate it a bit, and display it on the website. Currently I export the oracle data as csv files, import them using Drupal's Views module, and then manipulate/display it using another view. The problem is I have many csvs, the import process takes too much time and is too manual.

My question is, is there anyway I can import the data from oracle as a csv and manipulate it at the same time? If so how would I do this? Would it be in PHP or SQL?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to build in direct access to the Oracle database from Drupal.  If that is not possible, look at Oracle's Data Pump and External Tables features.